# Python nosetest doesn't work, but directly running it does using matplotlib's @image_comparison

Tags: python, matplotlib, nose, nosetests

I have this testing script, called `test_boxplot.py`:

```
__author__ = 'olga'

from matplotlib.testing.decorators import image_comparison
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import prettyplotlib as ppl
import os


@image_comparison(baseline_images=['boxplot'], extensions=['png'])
def test_boxplot():
    # Set the random seed for consistency
    np.random.seed(10)

    data = np.random.randn(8, 4)
    labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ppl.boxplot(ax, data, xticklabels=labels)
    # fig.savefig('%s/baseline_images/test_boxplot/boxplot.png' %
    #             os.path.dirname(__file__))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import nose
    nose.runmodule(argv=['-s', '--with-doctest'])
```

and if I run it directly, the tests all pass:

```
$ python test_boxplot.py
/Users/olga/workspace-git/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py:288: UserWarning: test module run as script. guessing baseline image locations
  warnings.warn('test module run as script. guessing baseline image locations')
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.224s

OK
```

but if I run it with `nosetests` it fails with this weird `IndexError` that centers around `matplotlib`'s `@image_comparison` decorator's code:

```
$ nosetests test_boxplot.py
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: IndexError (pop from empty list)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 286, in generate
    for test in g():
  File "/Users/olga/workspace-git/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py", line 145, in test
    baseline_dir, result_dir = _image_directories(self._func)
  File "/Users/olga/workspace-git/matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/testing/decorators.py", line 296, in _image_directories
    assert mods.pop(0) == 'tests'
IndexError: pop from empty list

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.092s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Any ideas what may be going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the decorator expects to be used in a subdirectory names "tests" of the main project dir (usually `project/tests` or more correctly: the module of the test must start with `something.tests.`). This is the code in  `_image_directories()`:

```
mods = module_name.split('.')
mods.pop(0) # <- will be the name of the package being tested (in
            # most cases "matplotlib")
assert mods.pop(0) == 'tests'
subdir = os.path.join(*mods)
```

`_image_directories()` has some special code in case of `func.__module__ == '__main__'` so you don't see the error in the first case.

Comment: Hmm yes, I'm in a `tests/` directory when I run it: `$ pwd    /Users/olga/workspace-git/prettyplotlib/tests`

but when I run `nosetests` in `/Users/olga/workspace-git/prettyplotlib` I get the same `pop from empty list` error

Comment: No, I think you need to run your tests from the repository root: have a look at the ggplot tests: https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/ -> Tests are in <root>/ggplot/tests, nose is called from <root>, so the tests are in modules like 'ggplot.tests.test_something'. If  you want you can also steal the test code in https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/blob/master/ggplot/tests/__init__.py, which reimplements the decorator and uses some other means to figure out the baseline-images dirs (line 64 and following).